# why does sendgrid import contacts show aws error?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to follow instructions for SendGrid Import Contacts (https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/import-contacts).
I am able to connect to SendGrid and get both the upload uri and the upload headers.
The subsequent call to the upload uri, though, won't work.
The error is

> SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

The call is built as such:

```
curl --upload-file "path/to/csv" "returned_url" -H 'x-amz-server-side-encryption: aws:kms'
```

Since I am trying to achieve this under php development, the command above is called in an `exec` function.
Since none of the aws part is under my management, I am having serious problems in debugging this call.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: There is [an example of using PHP to make this call](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/import-contacts?code-sample=code-import-contacts&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=%26gt%3B5.6) in the docs too. Have you tried that?

Comment: The call, as specified in the documentation, is useful only to get the the first uri to make the second call. This second call is the call that makes the file upload possible. I manage to have the first call working, but it's with the second (and undocumented) call that I am having issues.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I did not read the docs or your question correctly. Is the `x-amz-server-side-encryption` header the only header that the original API call returns?

Comment: @philnash no problem ;-). 
Yes, it is the only header returned by the original API

Comment: I was just able to do this by hand (get the upload URL from the API key, then plug it into `curl` on the command line) and it worked for me. Have you tried this to see if you get a different result? You can add `--verbose` to the `curl` command to see what it is doing and if there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

if you use sg api (not curl cmd) for sending import request and then use curl command for uploading cotacts csv, this error occur.instead try to send both request wiht curl command(for example in php use shell_exec())
hope this be useful

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue today on my PHP (Laravel) application and I managed to upload my CSV using Laravel HTTP Client using the following call:

```php
// Create the import request
$import_request = $sendgrid->client->marketing()->contacts()->imports()->put([
    'file_type' => 'csv',
    'field_mappings' => [...],
]);

$import_request_result = json_decode($import_request->body(), true);

// Upload CSV file
Http::send('PUT', $import_request_result['upload_uri'], [
    'headers' => array_column($import_request_result['upload_headers'], 'value', 'header'),
    'body' => file_get_contents('/path/to/your/file.csv'),
]);
```